# Precompilation Asp.net website in Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, azure, iis

I have a problem of deployment with my Asp.net website. So I activated the [precompilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb398860.aspx#FileHandlingDuringASPNETPrecompilation)

[image: config]

Sometimes when I deploy the website to the Azure App service, I get this error :

[image: demo]

I find a solution but it is not the best i think, I edit any file, via FTP,  in **App_code** Folder to force the recompilation of the website in prod.

So I need to know :

- What is the reason of this problem?
- How can I fix this issue?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

My application is a Asp.net website ( not a web application ) and it is a set of sub-websites which sometimes share the same namespaces and names of classes.

So when I deploy I can get different compilation errors in random places, I explain for example:

I edit a file in sub-website X and I publish it ==> I can get an error of compilation in a another random sub-website Y which worked fine before the publish !!
when I edit a file in **App_Code** and I pushed it via FTP the problem will be fixed

Comment: According to your description, we couldn't directly find why you get this error. Firstly, could you please tell us why your web application must use precompilation? Does it show any error? Besides,  you could change the debuge setting to true to show the details error message.

Comment: @BrandoZhang thank u for your comment. I edit my question

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think you choose the right way to design your project. If two website has no relationship, I don't suggest you use general class between these two site. Now the only way is as you say edit a file in App_Code and I pushed it via FTP. I suggest you could try to separate the web site and use its own class or page.